# Help Writing Nim/Take away Proof

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, computer-science

I'm new to proof by induction and found this: [A Take-Away Game](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/251-notes/games.pdf).

"Consider the following game: there are $n$ chips on the table. You are challenged by your arch-enemy to play the following game: you both have to alternate moves, where in each move, you can take away either 1, 2, or 3 chips from the table. The person who has no more chips to remove from the table chips loses."

It's very similar to the proof found here: [Variation of Nim: Player who takes last match loses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760842/variation-of-nim-player-who-takes-last-match-loses)...except player who takes last match wins.

Although I understand what is being said/explained in the proof on the first page, I'm not sure it's shown mathematically (like it is in the second link)?

For example, it says by inductive hypothesis - but I'm not sure what that would be? Is it $k=4a+b$? and why does this verify, mathematically, that the first player wins if n is not a multiple of 4? Would it be better explained using $n=0$(mod 4), and so on?

I'm trying to combine the two proofs from the links above to make a nice, easy to follow proof...but I'm coming up short.

Here is what I have so far:

n=4a+b $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}.$

The first player will win if and only if  $n \ne 4a$.

Base:

The first player wins if and only if $n \not\equiv 0$ (mod 4).

Let $n=0$

$n=4 \cdot 0 +0 = 4.$

The first player can pick up 1- 4 chips, and second player can pick up 1, 2 or 3 chips respectively (whatever is leftover), and the second player would win.

Let $n=1$

$n=4 \cdot 0 +1 = 1.$

The first player wins by picking up all of the chips.

Let $n=2$

$n=4 \cdot 0 +2 = 2.$

The first player wins by picking up all of the chips.

Let $n=3$

$n=4 \cdot 0 +3 = 3.$

The first player wins by picking up all of the chips.

Hypothesis-

Assume that in a game with $k$ or fewer matches, the first player will win for all $b=1,2,3$ such that $i \nmid 4$, and lose for all $b=0$ such that $i \mid 4$, $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$, $0 \le i \le k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \ge 3$.

Conclusion-

Suppose we have a game with $k+1$ matches with $k \ge 3$, therefore $k+1 \ge 4$.

If $k+1 = 4a+1$, the first player can pick up 1 chip, leaving $k=4a$ chips for the second player. By the inductive hypothesis, the first player will win.

**This is where I don't know where to go, because from here I'm left with:

If $k+1 = 4a+ 2$, the first player picks up 2 chips, leaving $k=4a-1$ sticks for the second player...

Comment: You should give the rules, not a link, at the start.  In your base case you say one player can take $1$ to $4$ while the other takes $1$ to $3$.  Usually the game is symmetric.  Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are claiming that Alice, the first player, wins if the pile is $1,2,$ or $3 \pmod 4$ and Bob, the second player, wins if the pile is $0 \pmod 4$.  your base case is that $0$ matches are a second player win (because Bob just took the last match) and $1$ to $3$ matches are a first player win (because Alice takes them all).  Then your induction says suppose we have verified it up through $k$ where $k \ge 3$.  Then we want to verify it for $k+1$.  If $k+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, Bob wins by taking $4$ less whatever Alice takes and getting to $k-3 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ which we know is a win for him.  Otherwise, Alice takes $k+1 \pmod 4$ and gets to a second player win.

It is easier to use the language of $P$ positions and $N$ positions from the [Sprague-Grundy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) for impartial games.

Comment: I think I'm still confused about how to connect the conclusion to the hypothesis. Is there a way to break down each case (1, 2 or 3 mod 4) in the conclusion?

Comment: Yes, when $k+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ you could list all three choices for Alice and the corresponding move for Bob, showing that in all three you get to $k-3$ which we have already proved is a win for Bob.  Then when it is not you could list the cases and show that Alice can leave a multiple of $4$ and win.

Comment: Okay, so let's say $k+1 \equiv 2$ (mod 4). Alice can remove 2, but that leaves $k-1 \equiv 0$ (mod 4) for Bob...but that would be a win for him, so that's counter to what I want to show.

Comment: ...I think. I'm also new to mod so I'm learning this as well. Would it not rearrange to $k \equiv 1$ (mod 4)?

Comment: mod is just the remainder, so $k \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ means $k=2,6,10,14\ldots$.  Yes, if $k+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ Alice takes $2$ and leaves $0 \pmod 4$ for Bob.  If you receive $0 \pmod 4$ you are losing.  If you leave $0 \pmod 4$ you are winning.